# Removing building data from LAS Dataset Layer in ArcGIS Pro to create tree canopy height layer

Tags: arcgis-pro, lidar, classification, las, canopy-height-model

I'm working with various lasd files of an arboretum in order to create a layer with heights for the tree canopy. I'm trying to remove buildings from the LAS dataset so that the layer only reflects tree elevation. Even when I deselect the classification code for buildings when generating a first return raster, after I filter for ground returns and minus them from the filtered first returns, I end up with buildings included in the data. Can I fully delete instead of filtering out a certain Lidar class from the file? Are the buildings not being filtered out because they're classified wrong?

Comment: Have you explored [this](https://learn.arcgis.com/en/paths/using-lidar-data-in-arcgis-pro/) learning path on using lidar data in arcpro?